# Free gift was added to your shopping cart

Tags: magento2.3

> Free gift %name was added to your shopping cart

When I add a promo product to the cart, a free product is added with it, I need to translate the popup message into another language, but I can't find anywhere how to do this, where I can edit this text in Magento 2, maybe someone knows?[image: Free gift was added to your shopping cart]

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was, the server version of the code was different and the repository did not have the plugin that displays this message. Always update the repository, other programmers can also work with it.

The phrase I was looking for
`Free gift <strong>%1</strong> was added to your shopping cart`